# Daisy chaining monitors with no DisplayPort on laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I purchased two U2414H monitors from Dell and am trying to connect them to my laptop (Inspiron 3421) but I don't have a DisplayPort on my laptop.

The laptop has 2-USB 3.0, 1-HDMI, 1-USB 2.0

The monitors have 1-DP (in), 1-miniDP (in), 1-DP (out), 2-HDMI

I have the monitors daisy-chained and bought an HMDI/DisplayPort adapter to connect to the first monitor but I can't get it to pull both monitors.

Is there something I'm missing or will it even work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For daisy chaining to work, the laptop itself must be connected via display port to the monitor. You cannot use an HDMI cable as it does not support MST.

Comment: What kind of hub do I need to look for? I've looked but I'm afraid I don't know exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Apologies, you cannot use HDMI at all. Revised my answer.

Comment: That's what I needed to know! Thank you so much for your help!