# Daisy chain 2 external monitors on laptop without DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, displayport, extended-desktop, daisychaining

I have:

- 2 Dell U2414H Monitors

  - 1 DP in
  - 1 mini DP in
  - 1 DP out
  - 2 HDMI
- A laptop with (No DisplayPort)

  - i7-4710MQ processor
  - 16GB DDR3 (2x8)
  - GT 840M - 2.0GB DDR3
  - 1 HDMI port
  - 2 x USB 3.0 PORTS & 1 x USB 2.0 PORT
  - 1 USB/e-SATA
  - 1 x 15 pin VGA OUT port
  - Windows 10

My ultimate goal is to use the **2 monitors** as **extended monitors** while no longer using my laptop screen. (Preferably by **daisy chaining** the 2 monitors.)

How would I go about achieving that goal? I did some research and came up with some options but I don't know for sure if they would actualy work (with my laptop and video card).

1. Use a USB to DisplayPort adapter: Would this work? Could I use something like [this](http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-3-to-Displayport-Video-Card-Multi-Monitor-Adapter-2560x1600~USB32DPPRO) or [this](http://www.tripplite.com/usb-3.0-superspeed-to-displayport-dual-monitor-external-video-graphics-card%20adapter-512-mb-sdram-2560x1600-1080p~U344001DP/) or [this](http://club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/usb-30-to-displayport-graphics-adapter.html)? Is such a device capable of MST/daisy-chaining?
2. Would I possibly need a DisplayPort hub like [this](http://www.startech.com/nl/AV/DisplayPort-Adapters/Triple-Head-DisplayPort-Multi-Monitor-MST-Hub~MSTDP123DP)? I assume such a thing is only necessary when a USB to DP on itself is not able of daisy chaining (MST)?
3. I assume that two devices such as mentioned in 1. would work, though this might become quite expensive.
4. Are there better/cheaper ways to achieve my goal?

PS: this question has about the same setup as [Daisy chaining monitors with no DisplayPort on laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/897094/daisy-chaining-monitors-with-no-displayport-on-laptop) but in that question there was no proposed solution for my problem (as none was asked).

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that your laptop can output to HDMI and VGA simultaneously?

Comment: I have not. How do I do that? Looking up graphic card specs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is a poor solution. Those adapters are "mini GPUs" that work over USB. Fine for spreadsheets and stuff, ok for youtube videos. Terrible for everything else. A waste of your 840M.
2. Is closer to what you want.

HDMI doesnt support chaining, so there isnt any great way to solve this. Best solution is to grab a HDMI male to VGA female adapter and use the two existing outputs. Obviously two cables isnt as nice as one, but buying 2x $110 adapters is no better but a lot more expensive.

Comment: According to Dell, VGA is not an option for this monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Linef4ult is absolutely correct, in regards to #1.

The #2 option  is a good solution as well, according to the english version of the web site, it'll work fine.  The adapter supports multiple displays, without mirroring, so it will effectively daisy chain the monitors.  But I suspect that the adapter / splitter requires specific windows drivers to be installed.  So this may not work with Linux, Unix, etc.

---

Edited, see below for better solution.

But absolutely **DO NOT** use VGA for those monitors.  VGA will not give you a clear image.  (I hope that Linef4ult meant an HDMI to DVI adapter, or DVI to HDMI adapter).

Instead of VGA, use the Mini DP and DisplayPorts, or use the 2 HDMI ports.  While not daisy chaining, the Mini DP, and Displayport ports, are relatively low hassle.

### New content

Okay, I missed something.  According to Dell, this monitor supports DisplayPort Chaining.

Outputs:

- 2 HDMI(MHL) connectors
- 1 Mini DisplayPort
- 1 DisplayPort (version 1.2a)
- **1 DisplayPort out (MST)**
- 1 Audio Line out (connect your speakers)
- 4 USB 3.0 ports - Downstream (4 at the back, 1 with battery charging)
- 1 USB 3.0 port - Upstream

So you should just be able to plugin one display port cable into the computer, and then one from the monitor to the other monitor.  Without installing any windows drivers, etc.

Comment: I was aware that the monitors supported chaining. The problem is that my laptop does not have a (mini) DP. Therefore my question asked if a USB/HDMI port of my laptop could be converted (with some adapter) into a DisplayPort that supports daisy chaining. My first option is such an USB to DP adapter but I don't know if it supports MST. The second option is a DP hub but I'd first need a DP for this to work. So implicitly the second option is: laptop USB -> via adapter (of option 1) -> DP -> DP Hub.

Comment: Missed that...  Sorry, but it's still possible.  I'm finding it hard to find, but there are HDMI to Displayport adapters that you should be able to use.   I don't know if you can chain with it, but I would check with StarTech regarding that.  For example, StarTech HDMI2DP HDMI or DVI to DisplayPort Active Converter, Sadly it's somewhat expensive ~$80 USD  - http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158264&cm_re=hdmi_to_displayport_adapter-_-15-158-264-_-Product